# Possible to check APK size from IntelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Anyone knows if it's possible to check APK size from IntelliJ? I cannot find this info on their site, but I've posted this question anyway.

Thanks

Comment: To add: any way to make output folder visible? Is it permanently disallowed to make them visible inside IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDEA doesn't show the APK size, you can check it in your favorite file manager.

Output folders are hidden by default, to show them you need to disable **Project Structure | Modules | Paths | Exclude output paths** option or change the location of the APK to the visible folder in **Android Facet | Compiler | Android Packaging Compiler | APK path**.

Comment: I did it and I do not see 'out' folder in my project. I even restarted IDEA and checked inside all directories. Synchronize didn't help as well. Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, I do not see it in Project View tree. However, I see in "Open Module Setting/Modules/Project_Name/Sources/Right_lower_windows" that the folder is set to visible (not set as source, test or excluded).